# Secure deleting object

Tags: symfony, entity

I have a table in which I can edit and delete all objects of the entity class persisted to the database.

When I now go to the delete-url: What is the best practise to secure the deletion, so that the user has to confirm the deleting?

A simple button or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No! Don't do this! Don't provide a URL that directly deletes anything!

GET requests should be idempotent, and not doing so is actually a [violation of the HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html).

Destructive actions within your application should execute as POST requests.

A JavaScript-driven confirmation dialog is a nice UI feature, but it *does not* fix the problem!

Comment: Hi, how do I do this best in the Symfony controller? Only listen on POST, encode POST data in Request, search entity and remove?

Comment: Yes, your deletion action should be restricted to POST method requests only, but you'll also need to update your table to generate the proper POST requests. Whether you implement that as an HTML form or as an AJAX call is up to you.

Comment: Hi,
what data should be in the post request?
The id, the whole object?

Comment: Usually just the id is enough. In this case I would do just the id myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the onclick event of the button with javascript and show a popup allowing the user to confirm the deletion.

Answer (score 1):

An alert on the button is not enough. If the URL is entered directly in your browser, the record is deleted. You need to ensure request is made with POST verb.